# dotnet watch start - starts http and https and opens a browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-3.1

In ASP.NET Core 3.1, dotnet watch start did not open a window and i dont know if it started http and https.
In the lates ASP.NET 5 a window with the http address goes up. I dont want windows to go up.
How can this be configured? I dont find anything for that which worked.

Its like:

> watch : Started
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
> info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
> Now listening on: https://localhost:5001

Regards

Comment: I believe this depends on the configuration you have for the other command you use, so if you use `dotnet watch run`, it depends on how you have configured `dotnet run`. If that opens a browser, so will `dotnet watch run`.

Answer (score 4):

Remove launchBrowser from launchSettings.json inside Properties folder

```json
    "mvctest": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true, /* this one */
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
```

Comment: I execute it within the console like:

"
dotnet watch run --no-launch-profile
dotnet bundle watch
"

How to do it there?

Comment: Something like this works, i need to use the ENV variable:

    "MyProjectName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://localhost:5001"
      }
    }